# XML parsing diference

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I would like to know what is the difference between StAX and SAX parsing in Java?

Can someone explain it as easy as possible, I don't understand what does it mean the one is pulling data and the other pushing?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-vs-stax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Push" and "Pull" refer to the style of coding that is used.

For "Push," you register a "handler" that the parser calls as it works its way through the document. So, you register your handlers with the parser and then tell it to parse the document. Your handlers will be called by the parser to tell your code when an element is starting, ending, etc.

For "Pull," your code is driving the step-by-step process of parsing the document. It is like getting an `Iterator` for the document and your code is going to loop and ask for the next element from the parser. In other words, your "handler" code is calling the parser for the next element to handle.

The different coding styles make different types of interactions with the document easier or harder. The choice of which style to use for a particular project is dependent on the requirements of that project.